# Получил токен для reCaptcha v2 через код ниже, вставил в textarea, а как его отправить, если кнопки Submit нет? Поиск не помогает

Tags: javascript, python, recaptcha

Вот код, далее html часть с капчой

`

```
from xmlrpc.client import TRANSPORT_ERROR
import requests
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from python_rucaptcha import ReCaptchaV2

RUCAPTCHA_KEY = "ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ"

SITE_KEY = "6Le1YRscAAAAAA4kHJVEL38P9BlfWaSMbl8f33Ps"

PAGE_URL = "https://www.sportmaster.ru/"

url = 'https://www.sportmaster.ru'        
s = Service(r'C:\Users\uwu\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=s) 
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#sticky-header-wrapper > div > div.sm-header-actions > button").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#app > div.sm-overlay.sm-overlay--active.sm-overlay--center > div > div > div.sm-dialog__template > div > section > div.auth-dialog__first.lrBoT > span > div > label.input-wrapper").send_keys("ХХХХХХХХХХ")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#app > div.sm-overlay.sm-overlay--active.sm-overlay--center > div > div > div.sm-dialog__template > div > section > div.auth-dialog__first.lrBoT > button").click()
time.sleep(1)

user_answer = ReCaptchaV2.ReCaptchaV2(rucaptcha_key=RUCAPTCHA_KEY).captcha_handler(site_key=SITE_KEY, page_url=PAGE_URL)

if not user_answer['error']:

    print(user_answer['captchaSolve'])
    print(user_answer['taskId'])
    js_string = '''
    function HUISOSALITRINEGRA() {
        var a = document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response')
        a.value = '%s';
     
        };

    HUISOSALITRINEGRA();
    ''' % user_answer['captchaSolve']
    driver.execute_script(js_string)
elif user_answer['error']:

    print(user_answer ['errorBody'])
    print(user_answer ['errorBody'])
#Тут должен быть клик по кнопке отправить капчу.
kodsms = input("Введите код из смс: ")
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#app > div.sm-overlay.sm-overlay--active.sm-overlay--center > div > div > div.sm-dialog__template > div > section > div.auth-dialog__second.t6USq > span > div > label.input-wrapper").send_keys(kodsms)
time.sleep(1)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)`
```

А вот, собственно, капча.

`<div><div class="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="none" style="width: 256px; height: 60px; position: fixed; visibility: visible;"><div class="grecaptcha-logo"><iframe title="reCAPTCHA" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6Le1YRscAAAAAA4kHJVEL38P9BlfWaSMbl8f33Ps&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc3BvcnRtYXN0ZXIucnU6NDQz&amp;hl=ru&amp;v=QENb_qRrX0-mQMyENQjD6Fuj&amp;size=invisible&amp;cb=ghdk2m8d7p2v" width="256" height="60" role="presentation" name="a-whbtu4w9z5tu" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div><div class="grecaptcha-error"></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea></div></div>`

Comment: Key.RETURN в текстовое поле поробуйте

Comment: В какое текстовое поле?

Comment: Вы результат разбора рекапчи куда вносите. Вот туда и руетурн.

Comment: Не помогло, если я правильно понял(